# how to read ASCII file with specific structure repeating every 25 lines?

Tags: c++, ascii

I have an ASCII data file which has different variables in 25 lines, that repeats. I want to make a loop over each structure and for every structure the elements would be added to an array. For example the first digit or number in the structure will be event number going from 1, 2, 3... etc, the second digit will be time of that event (in linux time format). here is sample of the repeating file.

```
   1   1481492919 298362 
   1     936    642    618   1346   2648      0    103   1651     69     76      7      0
   1    63   58   43   63   43    0   59   54   21   45   80   66   49   38
   1    50   65   39   67  119    0   87   47   79   78   50   73   24   35
   1    37   48   44   58   49   58   45   66   61   55   86  138   80   43
   1    32    0   45   95   49   54   57   62   42   55  107  162   67   40
   1  1688 1678 1675 1674 1670 1684 1707 1675 1687 1683 1686 1695 1693 1690
   1  2047 2047 2047 2047 1808 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047  648 2047
   1  1776 1770 1776 1797 1799 1790 1774 1768 1791 1784 1800 1789 1775 1747
   1  2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047
   1   108  155   97   84  100  109   98   90  292
   1  2047  581 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047
   1    45   44  175   60   50   55   48   39   22
   1  2047 2047 2047  610 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047
   1    65   77   53   78   52   53   46  134   40
   1  2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047 2047
   1    0 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   1    1 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000
   1    0 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   1    0 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please show what you have already done.

Comment: The [std::fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) class template has the necessary tools for the job.

Comment: @Serge yes I was able read and print the ascii in terminal with  ifstream f(aFile);
 string line;


 while (!f.eof()) {
 getline(f,line);


 if (line[0] == 'e' || line[0] == 'f' || line[1] == 'f' || line[1] == 'n' || line[2] == 'f')

  cout << "IGNORE LINE\n";

   else 
   cout << line << "\n";
 }

Comment: @Gunn Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46023776/edit) your post to include the relevant code.

Comment: Prefer to post code and data as text in your program.  Graphics depend on the resolution  and size of the Reader's monitor.  This may not be feasible to view on mobile phones or devices.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

A typical approach is to model each text line with a structure.  This can be called a *record*.

Looks like your file format has different types of records, so you will need different structures.

Inside each structure, overload `operator>>` to read members from a formatted stream.  This allows simpler programming:

```
Record1 r;
my_file >> r;
```

You can put the input statement into a `for` loop:

```
std::vector<Record> block_of_data;
Record r;
for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < 5; ++i)
{
  my_file >> r;
  block_of_data.push_back(r);
}
```

You can *model* the file by using the records in a structure.
Prefer to use `std::vector` than arrays, since you may not know the amount of data at compile time.

**Edit 1: Example**
The first row of the data contains two numbers.  So, let's create a class to model that:

```
class Record1
{
  public:
    int   x; // First number
    int   y; // Second number;
  // Overload operator>> to read in the numbers
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record1& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record1& r)
{
    input >> r.x;
    input >> r.y;
    input.ignore(10000, '\n'); // Eat remaining newline if there is one.
    return input;
}
```

Your input loop could look like:

```
int item_number = 0;
Record1  r1;
while (data_file >> item_number) // Read in first number on the text line.
{
    // Read the first line (record)
    data_file >> r1;  
    // ...
}
```

You next record contains 12 numbers, so it may look like:

```
class Record2
{
  public:
    std::vector<int>  data;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record2& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record2& r)
{
    // another technique:  read in as a line of text, then parse the string.
    std::string text;
    std::getline(input, text);
    std::istringstream  text_stream(text);
    int number = 0;
    while (text_stream >> number)
    {
        data.push_back(number);
    }
    return input;
}
```

The file reading loop:

```
Record1 r1;
Record2 r2;
int item_number;
while (data_file >> item_number)
{
  data_file >> r1; // Read first record;
  data_file >> item_number;
  data_file >> r2; // Read second record;
  // etc.
}
```

If you want, you could encapsulate the rows into one class:

```
class Data_Item
{
  public:
    int          item_number;
    Record1      r1;
    Record2      r2;
    //...
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Data_Item& d);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Data_Item& d)
{
    // Note: first number on row is item number.
    // Row 1
    input >> d.item_number;
    input >> d.r1;

    // Row 2
    input >> d.item_number;
    input >> d.r2;
    //...
    return input;
}
```

Your file would be a container of `Data_Item`, so let's read it in that way:

```
std::vector<Data_Item> database;
Data_item d;
while (data_file >> d)
{
    data_file >> d;
    database.push_back(d);
}
```

For more information about overloading input operator, search the internet for "c++ overload operator stream example".

I recommend obtaining Scott Meyer's *Effective C++* series, which contains explanations and examples of overloading the `operator>>` and `operator<<`.

Comment: Hi Thomas, forgive me but I am not a pro coder, just trying to learn. Your explanation is simply not getting in my head.

Comment: @Gunn:  See my **Edit 1** in my answer.